# SQLite.Swift giving Error 14 on Connection

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I have a routine, where the user chooses to pick a file location, then I try to create the file at that location.

First, I ask the user to choose a file path as follows:

```
    func ChooseCreateDBPath() -> String
    {
        var path : String = ""

        let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
        savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
        savePanel.showsTagField = true
        savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = "imported.sqlite"
        if (savePanel.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
            let result = savePanel.url
            if (result != nil) {
                path = result!.path
            }
        }

        return path
    }
```

Having obtained the string to the path where the DB will be created, the next routine runs.

```
        do {
            self.dbConn = try Connection(strFilePath)
            self.update_ui(message: "Created database: \(strFilePath)\n")
        } catch {
            self.update_ui(message: "Failed to create database : \(error)\n")
        }
```

.... this seems to run no problem.  I even see the sqlite file appear in the chosen location.

Now, I try to create the table and fields....

```
        do {
            let leads  = Table("leads")
            let idlead = Expression<Int64>("idlead")
            let email = Expression<String>("email")

            try self.dbConn!.run(leads.create { t in
                t.column(idlead, primaryKey: true)
                t.column(email)
                }
            )

            try self.dbConn!.run(leads.createIndex(email))

        } catch {
            self.update_ui(message: "Failed to create tables and indexes : \(error)\n")
        }
```

This then gives me:
"Failed to create tables and indexes : unable to open database file (code: 14)"

What I don't understand is how it can create the file, yet not be able to work with it?  Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Jase

Comment: If you can turn on extended error codes (I don't know how to do it in swift) you can get more information. Or display the full error message, not just the code (Again, don't know how to do that in swift...)

Comment: I have no idea if this help but try to use the prefix `sqlite3` for your database file. Also, you could get some GUI client for SQLite and see if you can connect to the file manually.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - The resulting file appears to be opening in a third party GUI client.  As expected, it is devoid of tables.... but it does open.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The macOS sandboxing doesn't like it when you have files outside the sandbox. Even though the user can choose the file, that doesn't give SQLite the permission to write temp journal files there, and so everything fails. My fix was simply turn to off the Sandbox.